# multiple deserialization of same object should or not create new instances?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, entity-framework, serialization

In my scenario i've a **MVC** on iis serializing objects from entity framework where i've overridden *GetHashCode* and *Equal* methods since **the Id of those objects is immutable once committed to the database.**
i also have some **client, who can't reach the database**, but connect to iis to get those entities serialized via json and deserialize them locally using newtonsoft.json.
When i deserialize them in the clients for a second time, to refresh the data in them, i was expecting the existing instances to be updated automatically.

I'm expecting a little too much?
Should i write some clone method to copy properties and check a cache for existing ids?
Did i wrote something wrong in the *Equal* and *GetHashCode* methods?

For instance:

1. I've a blog entity with a title in the database
2. The client connect to iis

   1. get a json string containing {"Id" : 1, "Name" : "blogName"}
   2. deserialize it and store it locally
   3. add post to the blog in the same way to an observable collection in the class blog i've used client side
3. Someone or something Change the blog name in the database
4. The client try to refresh

   1. get the json string containing {"Id" : 1, "Name" : "newBlogName"}
   2. deserialize it to a new instance of class blog, with same id

What's next? copy the new instance name to the old one, ore there's a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best solution is to have two database one server side and one client side, with the same shared entity framework but different connection strings, json.net with the keep object reference setted and use the network only to sync the databases and then query it client side.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you expect too much. You can attach new entity (because entity framework context doesn't know about this entity, because you get it from somewhere outside dbcontext) and then save it.

Answer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx)

```
//This place is where you can deserialize your entity
var existingBlog = new Blog { BlogId = 1, Name = "ADO.NET Blog" };

using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    context.Blogs.Attach(existingBlog);

    // Do some more work... 

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Actually i'm working in the client side of this, so i don't have a dbContext at all.
what becomes really painfull is handling the relationships during the refresh of data, since i get new istances from the deserialization and the old ones are still there.
I'm asking myself if i could use ef in an offline mode in the clients, so i can deserialize my entities in it like you described here.
Actually i rewrote all the entities classes to simulate the ef behaviour of relationship; and have some navigation property as observable collection to use them in bindings and mantain the rel in both sides.

Comment: Didn't get problem. Client side you don't need to care about saving (how to save) - you care only about to passing changed data back and there (server side) you check if data was changed (get actual data from db, update properties) and if changed - save. Try to look to serialized and deserialized objects as DTOs (data transfer objects) - this will make things easier to understand. And what is DTO? Simple data and not more.

Comment: i've updated the question hope it's more clear now.
The client's don't reach the database.
I din't mean to save the updated data to the database, instead, to get updated data from the database

Comment: Remove old entity and insert new. Btw, now your question doesn't have anything about entity framework. And it is unclear what is your client: windows app, web browser, silverlight...

Comment: it's a windows app, ef is mentioned for contestualization.

Basically your're saying it's the right way to write extra code to remove and relink relationships on deserialized entities? 

wonder why someone wrote this then: http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_PopulateObject_1.htm

Hope still someone comes out with a more elegant solution, if not i'll accept your's

Comment: It depends on what you need. For web client - it's good approach, for windows app - maybe it isn't, because reinserting causes UI blink...

Comment: You also loose selections and much more annoying stuff happens, that's why i decided to extend My poco classes with Methods to copy them over other ones after checking the id.